# X in a window in X

Tags: xorg

How can I create a new X in a window of the old X? A custom `.xinitrc` for the new X would be nice. I intend to use this for WM tinkering, so I don't break the WM I'm currently running.

Comment: What are you asking, running a window manager inside another window manager?

Comment: @Joe @Matteo @Blachshma @Shoe @Botz3000, this isn't off topic.  I came here for the answer to this question.  It's a programming question.  (Who else but a programmer would be looking for something like `xnest` or `xephyr`?)  Item 4 on this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic should be amended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Use [Xnest](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/Xnest.1.html).</s>

Use [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr).  It's an X server whose backend is an X window.

---

Recommendation taken from packages.debian.org:

> Use of the Xephyr X server instead of Xnest is recommended.

— https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xnest

> Xephyr is an X server that can be run inside another X server, much like Xnest. It is based on the kdrive X server, and as a result it supports newer extensions than Xnest, including render and composite.

— https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xserver-xephyr

Comment: Or [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr), which is the same concept, but about a decade newer, supporting a more modern set of X extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a virtual machine using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org).

The nice thing about that is you can modify pretty much anything and everything. If you work yourself into a hole, no problem; just revert to a snapshot or reinstall the virtual machine.

Comment: Depends on what you are going for. I've usually had a rough time playing around with `.XResources` and such. Making a virtual machine is painless and makes it easier to walk away from mistakes.